# Splitting column text file into smaller files based on value differences in Python

Tags: python, list, file, text, split

I am trying to split a text file with 3 columns into many smaller individual text files based on the presence of jumps in value in the first column. here is an example of a small part of the file to be split:

2457062.30520078    1.00579146  1

2457062.30588184    1.00607543  1

2457062.30656300    1.00605515  1

2457062.71112193    1.00288150  1

2457062.71180299    1.00322454  1

2457062.71248415    1.00430136  1

Between lines 3 and 4 there is a jump larger than usual. This would be the point where the data is split and the individually created text files are separated, creating one with the first three lines and one with the latter 3 lines. The jumps always exceed a change of 0.1 in the first column. The goal is to have any jump like this example be the split point to separate the files. Any insight is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through the main file and keep writing lines as long as your condition is met. That fits the definition of a while loop perfectly. The main complexity with this is that you need two open files at the same time (the main one and the one you are currently writing to), but that's not a problem for Python.

```
MAINTEXT = "big_file.txt"
SFILE_TEMPL = 'small_file_{:03.0g}.txt'
# Delimiter is a space in the example you gave, but 
#  might be tab (\t) or comma or anything.
DELIMITER = ' ' 

LIM = .1

# i will count how many files we have created.
i = 0

# Open the main file
with open(MAINTEXT) as mainfile:
    # Read the first line and set up some things
    line = mainfile.readline()
    # Note that we want the first element ([0]) before
    #  the delimiter (.split(DELIMITER)) of the row (line)
    #  as a number (float)
    v_cur = float(line.split(DELIMITER)[0])
    v_prev = v_cur

    # This will stop the loop once we reach end of file (EOF)
    #  as readline() will then return an empty string.
    while line:
        # Open the second file for writing (mode='w').
        with open(SFILE_TEMPL.format(i), mode='w') as subfile:
            # As long as your values are in the limit, keep 
            #  writing lines to the current file.
            while line and abs(v_prev - v_cur)<LIM:
                subfile.write(line)
                line = mainfile.readline()
                v_prev = v_cur
                v_cur = float(line.split(DELIMITER)[0])
        # Increment the file counter
        i += 1
        # Make sure we don't get stuck after one file
        #  (If we don't replace v_prev here, the while loop
        #  will never execute after the first time.)
        v_prev = v_cur
```

Comment: Wow this is working great up until the 20th file created until I seem to be getting a value error on line 33 for v_cur where it could not convert the string to float. Any idea what would cause that?

Comment: I think that it might actually be the end of the file, since I just realized that the conversion to a float happens before any check to see if the next line is empty. The cleanest way would probably be moving `readline()` and v_prev/v_cur assignments around. Alternatively, include an `if line:`...`else: break` or `try` around the v_prev and v_cur assignments. In that case you can also remove "`line and`" from the while statement above.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your file is test.txt so

```
f=open('test.txt').read().split('\n')
for i in f:
    frst_colmn,second_colmn,thrid_colmn = i.split('')
```

With you read the file , but what you want to do exactly???

Comment: The goal is to have a large 3 column text file separated based into individual text files based on the larger jumps in value in the first column. The issue is this jump comes in seemingly random intervals. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the jumps while reading the file

```
def reader(infile):
    number = float('-infinity')
    for line in infile:
        prev, number = number, float(line.split(' ', 1)[0])
        jump = number - prev >= 0.1
        yield jump, line

for jump, line in reader(infile):
    # jump is True if one must open a new output file
    ...
```